# iOS 11 - Crash on adding subview inside VKSideMenu

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, addsubview, uivisualeffectview

I have been using the [VKSideMenu](https://github.com/vladislav-k/VKSideMenu) library for implementing slide menu.
I have a created a button click for animating the same. The code was working **perfectly** before iOS 11 but since when I updated my iPhone to iOS11 the app gets **crashed** whenever I clicked on the button. Adding an exception breakpoint helped me to find out where the cause is but I could not found the reason for that cause anywhere .

In the `VKSideMenu.m` file, I got the issue at

`[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];`

where the `self.tableView` indicates the tableview for displaying the menu.
But the `tableview` was not nil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After hours of sitting, I finally got the solution. Replace this line

```
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

with

```
[[(UIVisualEffectView *)self.view contentView] addSubview:self.tableView];
```

If you want to add a subview ( for e.g., a subview named **subViewName**) to that view, you have to add this:

`[[(UIVisualEffectView *)self.view contentView] addSubview:subViewName];`